# Using class to get values from callback function?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have written a code and I want to use the values of linearposx,linearposy and yaw from the callback function named ComPoseCallback. As shown [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks), I did the changes in my program (created a class). But when I try to build it, it gives me the following error:

```
expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, &PioneerData::ComPoseCallback, PioneerData);
```

Here is my code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h" 
#include <ros/console.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>

double quatx;
double quaty;
double quatz;
double quatw;
double linearposx;
double linearposy;

class PioneerData
{
 public: 
 void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
};



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Test_FK"); 
    ros::NodeHandle n;                 
    ros::Publisher Velocity_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/RosAria/cmd_vel",1000);
    ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, &PioneerData::ComPoseCallback, &PioneerData);

    geometry_msgs::Twist velocity;
    velocity.linear.x =0.1;
    velocity.linear.y =0;
    velocity.linear.z =0;
    velocity.angular.x =0;
    velocity.angular.y =0;
    velocity.angular.z =0;
   
    geometry_msgs::Twist Stop;
    Stop.linear.x =0;
    Stop.linear.y =0;
    Stop.linear.z =0;
    Stop.angular.x =0;
    Stop.angular.y =0;
    Stop.angular.z =0;
   

   
   //std::cout<<"xPosition"<<linearposx<<std::endl;
   //ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  //ros::Rate rate (1);
  
  while (ros::ok())
   {
   
       
   if(Velocity_pub.getNumSubscribers()>0)
    {
    if (linearposx==0)
    {
    Velocity_pub.publish(velocity);
    
    }
    else if(linearposx>=0.5)
    {
      Velocity_pub.publish(Stop);
    }
    ros::spin();
     break;
    }
   }
    //return 0;
}

void ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)            
{
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("Position-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.position.x,msg->pose.pose.position.y, msg->pose.pose.position.z);
    ROS_INFO("Orientation-> x: [%f], y: [%f], z: [%f], w: [%f]", msg->pose.pose.orientation.x, msg->pose.pose.orientation.y, msg->pose.pose.orientation.z, msg->pose.pose.orientation.w);
    
   linearposx=msg->pose.pose.position.x;
   linearposy=msg->pose.pose.position.y;
   quatx= msg->pose.pose.orientation.x;
   quaty= msg->pose.pose.orientation.y;
   quatz= msg->pose.pose.orientation.z;
   quatw= msg->pose.pose.orientation.w;
   
   tf::Quaternion q(quatx, quaty, quatz, quatw);
   tf::Matrix3x3 m(q);
   double roll, pitch, yaw;
   m.getEulerYPR(yaw, pitch, roll); //getRPY
   ROS_INFO("Yaw: [%f],Pitch: [%f],Roll: [%f]",yaw,pitch,roll);

   return ;
}
```

I can't understand the reason for the error. Can you please point out my mistake?
Thanks.

**Edit** :Hi janindu, I did the changes suggested by you. I am getting the following error:

```
error: extra qualification ‘PioneerData::’ on member ‘ComPoseCallback’ [-fpermissive]
  void PioneerData::ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg);
```

**Edit 1**: I did a quick google search and found that I need to remove

```
Pioneer::
```

from:

```
void PioneerData::ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)
```

to remove above error shown in edit . After removing that error, I get a new error as you can see below:

```
CMakeFiles/Test_FK.dir/src/Test_FK.cpp.o: In function `main':
Test_FK.cpp:(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `PioneerData::ComPoseCallback(boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Odometry_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238689/using-class-to-get-values-from-callback-function??/) by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2016-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I figured out what your mistake is. The 4th argument in the `n.subscribe` method should be the context in which the callback should be called.

That is, instead of

```
ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, &PioneerData::ComPoseCallback, PioneerData);
```

you should first instantiate the PioneerData class like this.

```
PioneerData pioneerData;
```

Then call the subscriber method with a pointer to the object instance.

```
ros::Subscriber ComPose_sub = n.subscribe("/RosAria/pose", 1000, &PioneerData::ComPoseCallback, &pioneerData);
```

It should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

**EDIT**

Also, your `ComPoseCallback` method definition should be changed to

```
void PioneerData::ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)  { ...
```

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-07-04**:
Hi.Thank you for your reply. I have edited the post. Please have a look at it.

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-07-04**:
You have put the qualifier in `ComPoseCallback` declaration, not definition. Change the method **definition** as follows.

```
void PioneerData::ComPoseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry::ConstPtr& msg)            
{
    ROS_INFO("Seq: [%d]", msg->header.seq);
    ...
}
```

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-07-04**:
And you can refer http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ to see how to implement a class.
Let me know if you get further errors.

**Comment by [Tomm](https://answers.ros.org/users/27284/tomm/) on 2016-07-04**:
No more errors after the changes. Thanks a lot man.
Cheers.